# Remove group from WinJS.Binding.List

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have a `List` which is a `DataSource` for my `ListView`. When I add new `Items` to the `List`, everything works fine and the `ListView` is updated. However when I try to remove items from the `List` nothing happens... the `ListView` just doesn't care. How can I do that?

In fact is there an easy way to remove all `Items` from a certain group (I use the `GroupedSortedListProjection` as a `DataSource`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the below

Kind of manually reset the list (creating a new object on it)
**list =  new WinJS.Binding.List();**

notify the change done.

**list.notifyReload();**

this should reset your list (removing all the items from it)

Comment: I think I would loose the binding to the ListView by doing that. And of course I don't want to delete all items, only a few. :/

Comment: I see, try to use the slice (list.splice(positionYouWantToRemove, 1)) function to remove items from the list and than use the notifyReload 

 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700810.aspx